# Linking Geo server with osmdroid

Tags: osmdroid, geoserver

I have been trying to get WMS Tiles from geo server on osmdroid. But so far no success. I just manage to get a tiny version of tiles geo server which locates at some other location. Yes the projection is right because i am using this same layer for my web application too.
Following is my code

```
  MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
    XYTileSource tilesource = new XYTileSource("tiger:tiger_roads",0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{"http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0"}) {
@Override
 public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
                     return getBaseUrl() +"/tiger:tiger_roads/"+aTile.getZoomLevel()+"/"+aTile.getY()+"/"+aTile.getX()+".png";

                    }
    };
    tileProvider.setTileSource(tilesource);
    TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this);
    tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    map.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
    map.invalidate();
}
```

My logcat produces this as I keep on zooming in.
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /9/147/193 HTTP response: Not Found

Comment: That is because you didnt enter the layer name. Try this                                        http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger:tiger_roads/9/147/193.png

Answer (score 0):

Your server has 4 different URLs for that layer:

```
<TileMap title="Manhattan (NY) roads" srs="EPSG:4326" profile="global-geodetic" href="http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Atiger_roads@EPSG%3A4326@png"/>
<TileMap title="Manhattan (NY) roads" srs="EPSG:4326" profile="global-geodetic" href="http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Atiger_roads@EPSG%3A4326@jpeg"/>
<TileMap title="Manhattan (NY) roads" srs="EPSG:900913" profile="global-mercator" href="http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Atiger_roads@EPSG%3A900913@png"/>
<TileMap title="Manhattan (NY) roads" srs="EPSG:900913" profile="global-mercator" href="http://dev.propertyninja.com:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Atiger_roads@EPSG%3A900913@jpeg"/>
```

The fact that your tiles end up being too small suggests that you are using ESPG:4326 (latlon) instead of Google Web Mercator (EPSG:900913).

There is also the issue that you are using an XYZTileSource for a TMS layer - so there is a fair chance that the [Y coordinate is flipped](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720).